# Trying to vacuum all databases under /data with sqlite3, but fails with error 14

Tags: sqlite, optimization

I would like to vacuum all my database files under /data, to achieve somewhat better performance so I ran the following script:

```
for i in $(find /data -iname "*.db"); do
#echo $(basename $i);
sqlite3 $i 'VACUUM;';
resVac=$?
if [ $resVac == 0 ]; then
    resVac="SUCCESS";
else
    resVac="ERRCODE-$resVac";
fi;

sqlite3 $i 'REINDEX;';
resIndex=$?
if [ $resIndex == 0 ]; then
    resIndex="SUCCESS";
else
    resIndex="ERRCODE-$resIndex";
fi;
echo "Database $i:  VACUUM=$resVac  REINDEX=$resIndex" | tee -a /data/vacuum.log
done
```

As you can see this script vacuums and reindexes each database file under /data. REINDEX works fine, but VACUUM does not. **It returns "Error: unable to open database file". (error code 14)**

I am dealing with /data. So, it can't be a mount problem.

Comment: Is there an strace utility? Maybe that sheds some light. Also: is this an Android 4.2 device?

Comment: A quick unrelated shell scripting tip: you don't need a semicolon at the end of each line of your script. You only need semicolons to put more than one command on the same line (and inside SQL queries, as you know).

Comment: You might wish to read: [Android SQLiteOpenHelper cannot open database file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6202926/2533433) and [SQLite - Error 14 - SQLITE_CANTOPEN](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Error-14-SQLITE-CANTOPEN-td51751.html), the latter giving a good argument: *If the table is locked by another process the sqlite3_exec will through an error.* Not sure if that's your problem, though. [Google Search on "sqlite error 14"](https://www.google.com/search?q=sqlite+error+14) might give you additional hints.

Comment: no, the device has no strace, and it's not included in busybox. it is android 4.1.2 device.

Comment: and this script runs at early boot stage, so i do not think all of these databases are locked by other processes.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `REINDEX`, the `VACUUM` command needs to create a new temporary file to work in. It then replaces the database file with this temporary file. This means that it needs write access, not only to the database file, but also to the directory it's in.

Comment: Working on the databases below `/data` per se already requires root (even to read), so it's safe to assume above script has been running as root (or it would not be able to work at all). So file system permissions should be no issue -- or do I miss something?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't make a lot of sense to me either, but it's the only explanation I could find for why `REINDEX` might work but not `VACUUM`.

Comment: Admitted, you've made your point (as technically, this really *is* a difference). Though it shouldn't make a difference permission-wise. Confusing thing.

Comment: yes it's confusing to me too :) as Izzy pointed out this script runs as root.